# Automatic unlock of LUKS external data drive when plugged in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, luks, automount

I have set up LUKS for an external USB HDD with two protectors: a passphrase and a file key. I would like to automatically both unlock the drive and automount **when the drive is plugged in**.

I've set up entries both in `/etc/crypttab`:

```
externaldrive    UUID=0000000-0000-....    /root/externaldrive.key.luks     luks,noauto,nofail
```

and in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/externaldrive    /mountpoint    ext4    noauto,nofail    0 2
```

However, this does not work when I plug the drive in. I guess it's more related to unlock on boot or I'm missing some service that would do it (I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04, headless). Almost all questions here are relates to on-boot unlock.

Is it possible to unlock and mount LUKS-encrypted media automatically?

Comment: You can use the corresponding `.device` to "want" the corresponding [cryptsetup@.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup@.service.html)

Comment: See if [this method](https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile) helps.

Comment: @harrymc, unfortunately, no. I tried it before. From my understanding, it works only for 'persistent' drives that are available at boot; not on removable ones - once they are mounted.